# Select max value of index (V lookup Table)

Tags: python, vlookup

> 

```
I have to calculate F1 & F2 using following V Lookup table
```

> to calculate F1
> F1 = max{0, (A * F11 + B * F12 + C * F13)}
> From following combination of F11, F12, F13 calculate Max value of F1.
> Accordingly it should select max of index & its values of F21, F22, F23 at Index max & calculate F2

> To calculate F2

```
F2 = (A * F21 + B * F22 + C * F23)
Here A, B & C are the constants

e.g. If I am getting max value of F1 on **Index [5]** (F11=0.8730, F12=-0.3920, F13=-0.3616), 
to calculate F2, It should select F21=0.2256, F22=-0.4620, F23=0.0012 from same Index i.e. **Index [5]
```

**V Lookup Table as follows**

```
          1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
F11 -0.0083  0.1299  0.3297  0.5682  0.8730  1.1329  1.0602  0.6777
F12  0.5877  0.6826  0.4869  0.1875 -0.3920 -1.2367 -1.5999 -0.3279
F13 -0.0621 -0.1514 -0.2211 -0.2951 -0.3616 -0.4118 -0.3589 -0.2504
F21 -0.0596 -0.0189  0.0554  0.1089  0.2256  0.2878  0.2648  0.1561
F22  0.0721  0.0660 -0.0640 -0.1519 -0.4620 -0.8230 -1.1272 -1.3765
F23 -0.0220 -0.0289 -0.0261 -0.0140  0.0012  0.0559  0.1311  0.2506
```

Comment: What is your input? Reformating your question would be very nice too.
Do you get "F1" and "5" as your respective inputs? In what datastructure is your lookup-table?

Comment: Index 5 is an example. It may be any index. F1 = max{0, (A * F11 + B * F12 + C * F13)}. u can assume A=1, B=2, C=3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
A, B, C = 1, 2, 3
def exp(x, y, z):
    return A*x + B*y + C*z

F1 = exp(df.loc['F11'], df.loc['F12'], df.loc['F13'])
print(F1)
F2 = exp(*(df.loc[['F21', 'F22', 'F23'], F1[F1 == F1.max()].index[0]]))
F1 = F1.max()
print('F1:', F1)
print('F2:', F2)
```

I am getting for above values of A, B, C
F1 = 1.0408999999999997
F2 = 0.026400000000000007